# What ip address range to use for mailjet in gcp setup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mailjet

I am creating a firewall rule on gcp for mailjet. How do I choose what destination ip address range to use ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on : [Php Mailer Function not working on Google Cloud Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609112/php-mailer-function-not-working-on-google-cloud-platform)

> Under Destination filter, set 0.0.0.0/0 if you want to allow egress
>   traffic from the VM instance to any destination. If you want to limit
>   the destination, enter another IP range here. THIS IS IMPORTANT IF
>   YOUR EMAIL IS HOSTED SOMEWHERE ELSE.